# Sequelize not generating join table or get/add methods

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I run node 10.16.3 and sequelize 5.19.5. I created two models with a many to many relationship between them, using `sequelize model:generate`. It created both model and migration files. Supposedly, when I specify a many to many association, sequelize should generate the join table by itself, and also generate add methods on those models, so I can associate them properly. None of those things happened in my case after I ran `sequelize db:migrate` and `sequelize db:seed:all`. I saw many people just creating a join table manually, but I'd like to avoid that if there's a simpler way. Code files follow (with omitted imports for some constants that are irrelevant):

model Activity

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Activity = sequelize.define('Activity', {
    name: DataTypes.ENUM(cleaningActivity),
    category: DataTypes.STRING,
    baseRate: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    specialEquipment: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {});
  Activity.associate = function(models) {
    Activity.belongsToMany(models.ActivityBundle, {
      through: 'Activity_ActivityBundle'
    });
  };
  return Activity;
};
```

Activity migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Activity', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM(cleaningActivity)
      },
      category: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      baseRate: {
        type: Sequelize.FLOAT
      },
      specialEquipment: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      deleted: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Activity');
  }
};
```

Now, ActivityBundle model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ActivityBundle = sequelize.define('ActivityBundle', {
    name: DataTypes.ENUM(cleaningBundle),
    deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {});
  ActivityBundle.associate = function(models) {
    ActivityBundle.belongsToMany(models.Activity, {
      through: 'Activity_ActivityBundle'
    });
  };
  return ActivityBundle;
};
```

and finally, ActivityBundle migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('ActivityBundle', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM(cleaningBundle)
      },
      deleted: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('ActivityBundle');
  }
};
```

Then, I have a seed file, where I ma trying to first create bundles, then associate them to activities, like so:

```
module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

        const bundles = await ActivityBundle.bulkCreate(bundlesArray);

        return Activity.bulkCreate(activitiesArray).then(activities => {
            return Promise.all(activities.map(activity => {
                const bundlesPerActivity = activityBundleMapping[activity.get('name')]
                    .map(name => bundles.find(b => b.get('name') === name));
                return activity.addBundles(bundlesPerActivity); // this method does not exist, even though it should
            }));
        })
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    }
};
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong. What more am I supposed to define and where? I guess the migration files need to have some mention of many to many association? Not a clue, and official documentation is incomplete imho.

Answer (score -3):

You need to generate the join table yourself. Sequelize isn't *that* magical. :)

```js
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable(
      'Activity_ActivityBundle',
      {
        createdAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
        },
        updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
        },
        ActivityId: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        ActivityBundleId: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
      }
    );
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    // remove table
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Activity_ActivityBundle');
  },
};
```